# Non-self delegate is not called

Tags: swift, delegates, uikit

Consider the following code. Everything is done by the book, except that the delegate is assigned an instance of some other class other than self. Yet this code fails - the delegate is never called. Why is that?

```
class My: UITextField {
  ...
  init(...) {
    delegate = MyDelegate()
  }
}

public class MyDelegate: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
  public func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    print("MyDelegate was called")
  }
}
```

Comment: This line: `public override func didLoad() {` causes `error: method does not override any method from its superclass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your delegate property is defined using a `weak` var, the `MyDelegate` instance won't be retained. Without a strong reference it will shortly be deallocated and no longer exist to receive calls.

Your example code strays from the typical delegate pattern:

> **Delegation and the Cocoa Frameworks**
>
> [The delegating object is typically a framework object, and the
>   delegate is typically a custom controller object.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html)

The text field's view controller would commonly assign itself as the text field's delegate:

```
class MyViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

    ...

    func viewDidLoad() {
        myTextField.delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        print("textFieldDidBeginEditing")
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to expand this answer with how to resolve the problem (generally you'll want a strong property on `My` that holds onto `MyDelegate()`). This is a very common mistake, BTW. I made it just last week; took ten minutes to figure out why it wasn't working.

Comment: Thanks, that's indeed the issue. Within `UITextField`, the delegate is defined as `weak public var delegate: UITextFieldDelegate?`, which as @dene observed, doesn't retain things assigned to it, unless they are additionally referenced by someone else.

Comment: This is unhelpful; the OP did not want self as the delegate, they wanted a new class to handle the delegate calls.

Answer (score 0):

didLoad is not a function of UITextField so your delegate is not really set and that is why it is not called. If you are creating your My class programmatically, you can set the delegate after the instance is created.

```
let myTextField = My()
mytextField.delegate = MyDelegate()
```

If you want to set the delegate everytime you class is created, you need to override the init functions of UITextField and create the delegate inside your init functions.

```
class MyTF : UITextField
{
  override init(frame: CGRect)
  {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    delegate = MyDelegate()
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
  {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    delegate = MyDelegate()
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating a strong reference to your delegate class first with "let", and then setting the delegate. Otherwise, because the delegate reference is weak it will have a zero reference count and nil out, leaving you with no delegate.

```
let theDelegate = MyDelegate()
delegate = theDelegate
```